# Add a CSS filter to only one element in an SVG

Tags: css, svg

We are trying to add a gre/ayscale filter to an image in an svg.  This image is one of many in a group.  We see that the CSS is getting applied, however, when we try to apply it to an #`id` specifically within the group, and not the entire SVG, it doesn't work.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/kZJZb/)

HTML:

```
<svg id="svg-image">
    <filter id="grayscale">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                             0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                             0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                             0      0      0      1 0"/>
    </filter>
    <g>
        <image x="10" y="10" id="svg-image-gray" width="300" height="200" xlink:href="http://css-plus.com/examples/2012/03/gaussian-blur/i/fence.jpg" />
        <image x="10" y="250" id="svg-image-reg" width="300" height="200" xlink:href="http://css-plus.com/examples/2012/03/gaussian-blur/i/fence.jpg" />        
    </g>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
#svg-image-gray {
    filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */
}
#svg-image-gray:hover {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

We can put the filter on the image directly like so ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUehm/)):

```
<image x="10" y="250" id="svg-image-gray" width="300" height="200"
xlink:href="http://css-plus.com/examples/2012/03/gaussian-blur/i/fence.jpg"
filter="url(#grayscale)"/>
```

but this doesn't take advantage of CSS, and if there is any other CSS tied to the SVG or id, it doesn't work.  Trying to apply the filter to the group doesn't work either ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/kZJZb/7/)).

So how do you apply the filter to a specific #`id` in the SVG?

Comment: If I change the filter URL (on jsFiddle you don't have a `filters.svg`), then it works well for me in Chrome and Firefox (nothing else tested by me).